# pptp server 2003 hands out gateway from nic not dhcp server

Tags: windows-server-2003, rras, pptp

I have created a pptp RRAS server for a handful of clients to connect to. I would like them to use the servers default gateway (.1) for internet access. They are able to successfully connect (& see LAN) but it then cuts them off the internet. I understand that all internet traffic would be routed through the pptp server but that's ok since I have enough pipe. The problem seems to be that:

1. the clients gateway shows as their assigned RAS ip.
2. The clients assigned DNS settings seem to be what is set to the servers nic not what I have specified in dhcp (which is the same server). DHCP relay agent properties points to the nic DHCP is running on (192.168.100.163).  .1 is gateway in nic hw properties & dhcp. I have different dns secondary & third entries on my nic properties than what dhcp is configured for.

The problem is that I have a 10.10.1.x network that people can not see if they uncheck the gateway option but, they are then unable to see our other hosted sites on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answered this, I wanted to go ahead & let everyone know what I did to resolve it.

I'm still unclear why it appeared to be handing out the nic's dns settings but it doesn't matter now.

1. Go into DHCP scope options
2. add setting 249 "Classless static routes"
3. add the appropriate setting & save.
4. restart dhcp server & you should be good to go.

Have the users uncheck the "use remote server gateway" option under the clients tcp/ip network properties & now they can surf the net & reach every LAN resource even with different subnets.